# Execution time: why duration of the same code and same parameters can have a big difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the code - very simple.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PGetAccountRecentlyAmountAndCount_DEBUG]
AS
DECLARE @a DECIMAL (19,4) = 0
SELECT @a = ISNULL(SUM(FValidBet * 150 / 100), 0) FROM [dbo].[TOrder_Bak10](NOLOCK) A
```

I've monitored all executions, they have same plan handle.

Then I've cleaned the plan cache and buffers cache before executing the sp using this:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Still nothing changes.

I'm pretty sure they're all executed with a same plan and no cache exists at the same time. So I just can't understand what the else reason could be.

And this table which has no update or insert or select at another sp. Only here.

Hope someone can give me any direction.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt5FP.png)

Comment: You have no WHERE clause on the table TOrder_Bak10 .  This makes the context of your situation seem odd or theoretical. .  Or eventually you are going to have 10 million rows in your query and wonder why it is slow.   Usually the issue you are bringing up is why the concept of  OPTION (RECOMPILE) Exists.   If you are on a production system avoid DBCC commands like FREEPROCCACHE unless you are the one responsible for the database and have confidence you know what the DBCC commands side effects will do to your systems.

Comment: really thx for reply. this's only a example which running in my test environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that looks like a query typicaly running at 50ms unless something else gets in it's way.

since you have nolock turned on, the table size must be of some significance - is this io & the duration is overhead waiting for the pages to be loaded (note that this also could be cache contention loading from RAM to the CPU, not only disk io)

Possibly it is counting the compile overhead if in the background you are clearing buffers & freeing the proccache.

I don't know if this will parallise - you could hit some overhead if this varies (since the results have to be merged)

Is it on a single thread but that is briefly stalling while that cpu core does? something else.

You probably going to have to find some way of getting the actual execution stats back for each call...

Comment: i give it up. hah. lol. honestly is not my business. we have DBA.  but i've found some interest things. like all the Datas created in memory or cache or buffer whatever it called. it even happened after i created a new temporary table. and while i analyzed those same query plans of online database and local. CPU costs are very stable and fast in any worker threads. so. maybe it's memory pressure issues. cuz as i said. all datas in memory. and many expensive query happened every seconds. anyway. thx your post. i'm appreciate it.